# How efficient is category tree DB design?

Tags: sql, database

Many times when we normalize we found this scenario

```
    car(id, tag, year, make_id, model_id)
    make(id, name)
    model(id, name, make_id)
```

I'm trying to solve this with a category design

```
    car(id, tag, year, make_category_id, model_category_id)
    category (id, name, description, parent_category_id) //this works like a tree
```

with this I can solve other problems in the same database like:

```
    contact(id, nickname, phone_id, email_id, address_id, person_id, company_id)
    email(id, email_value, category_id) //category represent the Type(Personal, Work)
    phone(id, phone_value, category_id) //category represent the Type(Cell, Home, Work,..)
    address(id, address_value, category_id)//category represent the type(Billing, Physical)
```

So, putting all categories in the same table give me the flexibility to create categories indefinitely in a tree, but my question is: How efficient is this approach?
Thanks

[Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X46Up.png)

This is not for Access dbm but I run quick test of SQL in access to fill Combo boxes on forms.

In a form for email contact I populated email type combo box with:

```
    SELECT c.name AS Category, category.name AS Subcategory, category.id
    FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category ON c.id=category.parentcategory
    WHERE c.[name]='Email';//CB populated with subcategories from Email parent category
```

In a form for car I populated make combo box with:

```
    SELECT c.name AS Category, category.name AS Subcategory, category.id
    FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category ON c.id=category.parentcategory
    WHERE c.[name]='Vehicle';//CB populated with subcategories from Vehicle parent category
```

and combo box model in the same car form populated with:

```
    SELECT c.name, c.id
    FROM category AS c
    WHERE (((c.parentcategory)=[Forms]![Car]![Combo38]));//CB populated with subcategories from Make selected parent category
```

Comment: Your design is not particularly efficient, and quite difficult in some databases.  Instead of just the parent, include the full path for the categories.  That is much more efficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: in my experience recursive queries (which are needed are needed for this model) are pretty efficient - or at least efficient enough for all my use cases. Storing the full path is actually **very** inefficient if you need to _update_ the hierarchy. DBMS _not_ supporting [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) are the exception, not the rule nowadays

Comment: I understand the model, but I'm not clear on what problem it is solving...?

Comment: @PhilipKelley I'm trying to eliminate the tables you get after normalizing that only have a text attribute and create the flexibility to add or change categories without changing the database design.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I am presuming that using the category hierarchy happens about a 1000 times more often than updating them -- which is more in line with my experience.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so hierarchy or full path?? full path is like formatting text, I don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have hit upon a variant of OTLT, the “One True Lookup Table” database design anti-pattern. There are many, many articles on the web that discuss in detail why this can be a Bad Thing. Google “One True Lookup Table”, or even just OTLT, read a couple, and determine for yourself if this is appropriate for what your are working on now.

As a good start, here’s an article on the subject by Phil Factor on the SimpleTalk site: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2008/05/29/when-the-fever-is-over-and-ones-work-is-done/

Comment: Probably you are right so is there a enough efficient way to manage this. I know that I'm not trying to make substitutions of data types, hierarchy or objects, and I don't think that this is a unique Idea but I need a category schema because the users wanna change or add concepts sometimes on the fly. So I have this pattern: many terms that people wanna manage dynamically and are different tables just with ids and texts; is bad to see that as categories or concepts? Any way is difficult, thanks.

Comment: One dedicated system per data attribute set vs. a “one size fits all” system is the short-term problem, but (aside from declarative relational integrity) a bigger issue is how does it work in the long term? Does it continue to function properly as values are added (and removed/disabled) from the myriad sets? Is it simple and efficient to use the data as it will need to be used, or will the necessary programming become an impediment to growing or modifying the system as new requirements come in?

Comment: Creating code and structures is all well and good, but don’t overlook the three Ms: Management, Maintenance and Modification.

Comment: You are absolutely right I'm going to investigate more my data model i'm not really in a rush so I don't have to make a decision right now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also have for address: country(id, name, shortname, iso2, iso3), state(id, name, shortname, iso2, iso3, country_id), city(id, name, abbreviation, state_id) and I never put in my mind consider these as categories because I know the important of data persistence and queries for ER and the three Ms. So all of these, making a summary from what I'm learning form you, is gonna be a matter of complexity.